# TypeScript set string = null fails, but null! works

Tags: typescript, null

In my TypeScript class, why does this fail:

```
export class MyClass {
    x:string = null //throws IDE warning (type 'null' is not assignable to 'String')
}
```

but this works:

```
export class MyClass {
    x:string = null!
}
```

I don't understand what `null!` even is.  A guaranteed-to-be-not-null null?

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect that to produce the type `never` (which would not be assignable). Same thing here: `const y = 5 as never; const x: string = y;` doesn't error

Answer (score 3):

`!` asserts not null, so it removes the null type, leaving you with the empty union, or `never`. The [never type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) is special in that it is a subtype of every type and is assignable to every type (since it should never happen). That's why you get no error.

For the record, you can verify this yourself:

```js
const x = null!; // mouse over x and you'll see that it's type "never"

const y: string = 42 as never; // this doesn't error since never is assignable to everything
```